# How to give assertion to the void methods in Xunit Test c#.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit.net

I want to add an assert method after Act section.
AddStudents method is a void method

Below is the code

```
  [Fact()]

   public async Task AddStudent()
        {
            //Arrange
             
            StudentDto student= StudentDataSource.studentDto();
           _studentRepositoryMock.Setup(s => s.AddStudents(student));
             
            // Act           
            _studentService.AddStudents(student);

           //Assert
        }
```

Comment: Depends on what exactly do you need to assert?

Answer (score 0):

To be useful, a void method must have some observable side effect. That side effect should be described in the method's documentation. In this case, the side effect could probably be summarized as *the added student can be retrieved from the service.* You could assert this by attempting to retrieve the student you just added and testing for logical equality with the original `student`. If the void method is documented to throw exceptions under certain conditions (such as if the student already exists) then you should also write tests for those scenarios.